# Interactively deforming a polygon in matplotlib

Tags: python, matplotlib

I would like to implement something like MATLAB's `drawfreehand` in Python.

I have something that is similar below where the user draws a poly gone which is then simplified using Shapely and then has an interactive spline fit to it. the issue is that the spline fit will often bulge out beyond the limits of the original polygon. My code is below:

```
from matplotlib.patches import Polygon
from matplotlib.widgets import AxesWidget
from matplotlib.lines import Line2D
import matplotlib as mpl
from matplotlib import path
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from scipy import interpolate
from shapely.geometry import LinearRing, Polygon as shapelyPolygon
import numpy as np
import copy

class AxManager:
    def __init__(self, ax):
        self.artists = []
        self.ax = ax
        self.canvas = self.ax.figure.canvas
        self.useblit = self.canvas.supports_blit
        self.canvas.mpl_connect('draw_event', self.update_background)
        self.background = None


    def update(self):
        """draw using newfangled blit or oldfangled draw depending on
        useblit
        """
        if not self.ax.get_visible():
            return False
        if self.useblit:
            if self.background is not None:
                self.canvas.restore_region(self.background)
            for artist in self.artists:
                if artist.get_visible():
                    self.ax.draw_artist(artist)
            self.canvas.blit(self.ax.bbox)
        else:
            self.canvas.draw_idle()
        return False
    def draw(self):
        self.canvas.draw_idle()

    def update_background(self, event):
        """force an update of the background"""
        # If you add a call to `ignore` here, you'll want to check edge case:
        # `release` can call a draw event even when `ignore` is True.
        if self.useblit:
            self.background = self.canvas.copy_from_bbox(self.ax.bbox)


class mySelectorWidget(AxesWidget):
    def __init__(self, axMan, button=None, state_modifier_keys=None):
        AxesWidget.__init__(self, axMan.ax)

        self.visible = True
        self.axMan = axMan
        self.artists=[]
        self.connect_event('motion_notify_event', self.onmove)
        self.connect_event('button_press_event', self.press)
        self.connect_event('button_release_event', self.release)
        self.connect_event('key_press_event', self.on_key_press)
        self.connect_event('key_release_event', self.on_key_release)
        self.connect_event('scroll_event', self.on_scroll)

        self.state_modifier_keys = dict(move=' ', clear='escape',
                                        square='shift', center='control')
        self.state_modifier_keys.update(state_modifier_keys or {})

        if isinstance(button, int):
            self.validButtons = [button]
        else:
            self.validButtons = button

        # will save the data (position at mouseclick)
        self.eventpress = None
        # will save the data (pos. at mouserelease)
        self.eventrelease = None
        self._prev_event = None
        self.state = set()

    def set_active(self, active):
        AxesWidget.set_active(self, active)
        if active:
            self.axMan.update_background(None)

    def ignore(self, event):
        """return *True* if *event* should be ignored"""
        if not self.active or not self.ax.get_visible():
            return True

        # If canvas was locked
        if not self.canvas.widgetlock.available(self):
            return True

        if not hasattr(event, 'button'):
            event.button = None

        # Only do rectangle selection if event was triggered
        # with a desired button
        if self.validButtons is not None:
            if event.button not in self.validButtons:
                return True

        # If no button was pressed yet ignore the event if it was out
        # of the axes
        if self.eventpress is None:
            return event.inaxes != self.ax

        # If a button was pressed, check if the release-button is the
        # same.
        if event.button == self.eventpress.button:
            return False

        # If a button was pressed, check if the release-button is the
        # same.
        return (event.inaxes != self.ax or
                event.button != self.eventpress.button)

    def _get_data(self, event):
        """Get the xdata and ydata for event, with limits"""
        if event.xdata is None:
            return None, None
        x0, x1 = self.ax.get_xbound()
        y0, y1 = self.ax.get_ybound()
        xdata = max(x0, event.xdata)
        xdata = min(x1, xdata)
        ydata = max(y0, event.ydata)
        ydata = min(y1, ydata)
        return xdata, ydata

    def _clean_event(self, event):
        """Clean up an event

        Use prev event if there is no xdata
        Limit the xdata and ydata to the axes limits
        Set the prev event
        """
        if event.xdata is None:
            event = self._prev_event
        else:
            event = copy.copy(event)
        event.xdata, event.ydata = self._get_data(event)

        self._prev_event = event
        return event

    def press(self, event):
        """Button press handler and validator"""
        if not self.ignore(event):
            event = self._clean_event(event)
            self.eventpress = event
            self._prev_event = event
            key = event.key or ''
            key = key.replace('ctrl', 'control')
            # move state is locked in on a button press
            if key == self.state_modifier_keys['move']:
                self.state.add('move')
            self._press(event)
            return True
        return False

    def _press(self, event):
        """Button press handler"""
        pass

    def release(self, event):
        """Button release event handler and validator"""
        if not self.ignore(event) and self.eventpress:
            event = self._clean_event(event)
            self.eventrelease = event
            self._release(event)
            self.eventpress = None
            self.eventrelease = None
            self.state.discard('move')
            return True
        return False

    def _release(self, event):
        """Button release event handler"""
        pass

    def onmove(self, event):
        """Cursor move event handler and validator"""
        if not self.ignore(event):
            event = self._clean_event(event)
            if self.eventpress:
                self._ondrag(event)
            else:
                self._onhover(event)
            return True
        return False

    def _ondrag(self, event):
        """Cursor move event handler"""
        pass
    def _onhover(self, event):
        pass

    def on_scroll(self, event):
        """Mouse scroll event handler and validator"""
        if not self.ignore(event):
            self._on_scroll(event)

    def _on_scroll(self, event):
        """Mouse scroll event handler"""
        pass

    def on_key_press(self, event):
        """Key press event handler and validator for all selection widgets"""
        if self.active:
            key = event.key or ''
            key = key.replace('ctrl', 'control')
            if key == self.state_modifier_keys['clear']:
                for artist in self.artists:
                    artist.set_visible(False)
                self.update()
                return
            for (state, modifier) in self.state_modifier_keys.items():
                if modifier in key:
                    self.state.add(state)
            self._on_key_press(event)

    def _on_key_press(self, event):
        """Key press event handler - use for widget-specific key press actions.
        """
        pass

    def on_key_release(self, event):
        """Key release event handler and validator"""
        if self.active:
            key = event.key or ''
            for (state, modifier) in self.state_modifier_keys.items():
                if modifier in key:
                    self.state.discard(state)
            self._on_key_release(event)

    def _on_key_release(self, event):
        """Key release event handler"""
        pass

    def set_visible(self, visible):
        """ Set the visibility of our artists """
        self.visible = visible
        for artist in self.artists:
            artist.set_visible(visible)

    def addArtist(self, artist):
        self.axMan.artists.append(artist)
        self.artists.append(artist)

class myLasso(mySelectorWidget):
    def __init__(self, axMan, onselect=None, button=None):
        super().__init__(axMan, button=button)
        self.onselect = onselect
        self.verts = None
        self.polygon = Polygon([[0,0]], facecolor=(0,0,1,.1), animated=True, edgecolor=(0,0,1,.8))
        self.polygon.set_visible(False)
        self.ax.add_patch(self.polygon)
        self.addArtist(self.polygon)
#        self.set_active(True) #needed for blitting to work

    def _press(self, event):
        self.verts = [self._get_data(event)]
        self.set_visible(True)

    def _release(self, event):
        self.disconnect_events()
        if (self.verts is not None) and (self.onselect is not None):
            self.onselect(self.verts)
        self.set_visible(False)
        self.axMan.draw()

    def _ondrag(self, event):
        if self.verts is None:
            return
        self.verts.append(self._get_data(event))
        self.polygon.set_xy(self.verts)
        self.axMan.update()


class PolygonInteractor(mySelectorWidget):
    """
    A polygon editor.
    https://matplotlib.org/gallery/event_handling/poly_editor.html
    Key-bindings
      't' toggle vertex markers on and off.  When vertex markers are on,
          you can move them, delete them
      'd' delete the vertex under point
      'i' insert a vertex at point.  You must be within epsilon of the
          line connecting two existing vertices
    """
    showverts = True
    epsilon = 5  # max pixel distance to count as a vertex hit

    def __init__(self, axMan):
        super().__init__(axMan, None)    

        self.line = Line2D([0],[0], ls="",
                           marker='o', markerfacecolor='r',
                           animated=True)
        self.ax.add_line(self.line)
        self._ind = None  # the active vert
        self._hoverInd = None

        self.line2 = Polygon([[0,0]], animated=True, facecolor=(0,0,1,.1), edgecolor=(0,0,1,.9))
        self.ax.add_patch(self.line2)
        self.addArtist(self.line2)
        self.addArtist(self.line)
        self.set_visible(False)

    def initialize(self, verts):

        x, y = zip(*verts)
        self.line.set_data(x,y)
#        xy=[[0,0],[100,100],[0,100]]
        xy = self.interpolate()
        self.line2.set_xy(xy)
        self.set_visible(True)
#        self.axMan.update()

    def interpolate(self):
        x,y = self.line.get_data()
        tck, u = interpolate.splprep([x, y], s=0, per=True)   
        # evaluate the spline fits for 1000 evenly spaced distance values
        xi, yi = interpolate.splev(np.linspace(0, 1, 1000), tck)
        return list(zip(xi,yi))

    def get_ind_under_point(self, event):
        'get the index of the vertex under point if within epsilon tolerance'
        # display coords
        xy = np.asarray(list(zip(*self.line.get_data())))
        xyt = self.line.get_transform().transform(xy)
        xt, yt = xyt[:, 0], xyt[:, 1]
        d = np.hypot(xt - event.x, yt - event.y)
        indseq, = np.nonzero(d == d.min())
        ind = indseq[0]
        if d[ind] >= self.epsilon:
            ind = None

        return ind

    def _press(self, event):
        'whenever a mouse button is pressed'
        if not self.showverts:
            return
        if event.inaxes is None:
            return
        if event.button != 1:
            return
        self._ind = self.get_ind_under_point(event)

    def _release(self, event):
        'whenever a mouse button is released'
        if not self.showverts:
            return
        if event.button != 1:
            return
        self._ind = None

    def _on_key_press(self, event):
        'whenever a key is pressed'
#        if not event.inaxes:
#            return
        if event.key == 't':
            self.showverts = not self.showverts
            self.line.set_visible(self.showverts)
            if not self.showverts:
                self._ind = None
        elif event.key == 'd':
            ind = self.get_ind_under_point(event)
            if ind is not None:
                self.poly.xy = np.delete(self.poly.xy,
                                         ind, axis=0)
                self.line.set_data(zip(*self.poly.xy))
        elif event.key == 'i':
            xys = self.poly.get_transform().transform(self.poly.xy)
            p = np.array([event.x, event.y])  # display coords
            for i in range(len(xys) - 1):
                s0 = xys[i]
                s1 = xys[i + 1]
                d = np.linalg.norm(np.cross(s0-s1, s1-p))/np.linalg.norm(s0-s1) #distance from line to click point
                if d <= self.epsilon:
                    self.line.set_data(np.insert(self.line.get_data, i+1, [event.ydata, event.xdata], axis=0))
                    break
        elif event.key == 'enter':
            self.done = True
            self.close()
            return
        if self.line.stale:
            self.canvas.draw_idle()

    def _onhover(self, event):
        lastHoverInd = self._hoverInd
        self._hoverInd = self.get_ind_under_point(event)
        if lastHoverInd != self._hoverInd:
            if self._hoverInd is not None:
                self.line.set_markerfacecolor((0,.9,1,1))
            else:
                self.line.set_markerfacecolor('r')
        self.axMan.update()

    def _ondrag(self, event):
        'on mouse movement'

        if self._ind is None:
            return
        x, y = event.xdata, event.ydata
        d = list(zip(*self.line.get_data()))
        d[self._ind] = (x,y)
        if self._ind == 0:
            d[-1] = (x, y)
        elif self._ind == len(d) - 1:
            d[0] = (x, y)
        self.line.set_data(list(zip(*d)))

        xy = self.interpolate()
        self.line2.set_xy(xy)
        self.axMan.update()


if __name__ == '__main__':

    fig, ax = plt.subplots()
    def onselect(verts):
        l = shapelyPolygon(LinearRing(verts))
        l = l.buffer(0)
        l=l.simplify(l.length/2e2, preserve_topology=False)  
        p.active=True
        p.initialize(l.exterior.coords)
    axm = AxManager(ax)
    l = myLasso(axm, onselect=onselect)
    p = PolygonInteractor(axm)
    p.active = False
```

Does anyone know how I can more closely implement the reshaping functionality of MATLAB's `freehand` object?